# can not invoke chromedriver on Linux (debian) machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Resources: VM -Debian Linux , Selenium 4 , Chrome V78, ChromeDriver , Jenkins , Maven, JAVA 8

**Issue:** I can not invoke chromedriver on Linux (debian) machine.

I can see message "Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code."

on Jenkins.

Maven command : clean install test

Log Trace:::
```

[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
    Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven/pom.xml clean install test
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Land ---

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!

[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven/target/test-classes

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) @ Land ---

[INFO]

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------

[INFO]  T E S T S

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Running TestSuite

[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:26.644 [main] BaseClass -     [32mINFO[m - Creating Screenshot folder for this current execution.

directory is  : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven/screenshots

directory is exist /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven/logs

directory is exist /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven/test-output

[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:26.655 [main] SetUpTest -     [32mINFO[m - ============================================================    
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:26.655 [main] SetUpTest -     [32mINFO[m - ====== Initializing Driver, Starting Browser Session =========    
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:26.655 [main] SetUpTest -     [32mINFO[m - ============================================================    
projectPath is: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven    
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:26.656 [main] BaseClass -     [32mINFO[m - projectPath is: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Maven    
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:26.656 [main] BaseClass -     [32mINFO[m - Driver value is : null    
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:26.656 [main] BaseClass -     [32mINFO[m - chrome driver is here

Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.11 (eaaae9de6b8999773fa33f92ce1e1bbe294437cf-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#86}) on port 4878

Only local connections are allowed.

**Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.**

[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.930 [main] SetUpTest - 
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.930 [main] SetUpTest -  ============ createAccount Test case is Started. ==============
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.931 [main] SetUpTest -  
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.932 [main] TestListener  - 
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.933 [main] TestListener  - ===== createAccount - Test case is Skipped =======
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.934 [main] TestListener  - 
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.934 [main] TestListener  - ===== createAccount - Test case is Failed =======
[INFO ] 2019-09-18 21:51:27.941 [main] BaseClass -  ******** Disposing Browser Driver **********    
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0    
[INFO]    
[ERROR] There are test failures. This is the final result
----------------------------------------------------------------

**My code :**
```

This is my Selenium code:

```
if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--verbose");
options.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips=''");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
```

These are options I have tried on chromedriver so far

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // This line is not being invoked successfully.

------------------------------------------        

What I tried so far:

1. I tried firefox browser - which is not launching as well

2. I tried to "chmod 777" files, drivers and folders as per requirement

3. I set up few chrome "options.addArguments" to "disbale GPU" , "headless"  and "no sandbox" as per google

4. I looked in VM that if there are already multiple instance opened for Chromedriver via "htop" and other commands to kill the older sessions but I did not see any chrome because it's never been launched

5. https://stgconsulting.com/running-automated-selenium-tests-from-jenkins-on-linux/

6.  https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu
```

Answer (score -1):

Resources: Maven, Chrome,ChromeDriver, Linux(Debian), Java, Testng, jenkins

Link I followed for basic Linux (Debian) set up : https://stgconsulting.com/running-automated-selenium-tests-from-jenkins-on-linux/

***Before solution we have been seeing this below error***:

[INFO ] 2019-09-20 09:41:19.341 [main] BaseClass - browserName value is : chrome
[INFO ] 2019-09-20 09:41:19.341 [main] BaseClass  - chrome driver is here
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.11 (eaaae9de6b8999773fa33f92ce1e1bbe294437cf-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#86}) on port 29688
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[INFO ] 2019-09-20 09:41:23.904 [main] SetUpTest -  ==========================================================
[INFO ] 2019-09-20 09:41:23.904 [main] SetUpTest -  =========== createAccount Test case is Started.

---

***After solution I am not seeing failure/error and I am able to execute lest on Linux (Debian)***:

[INFO ] 2019-09-20 08:46:30.675 [main] BaseClass - chrome driver is here
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b07dc18a74666574f19176731995c-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1155}) on port 9770
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1568994392.814][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 76.
Sep 20, 2019 8:46:33 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[INFO ] 2019-09-20 08:46:33.227 [main] BaseClass - Browser is Chrome

---

solution steps and information:

(1) You can have latest Chrome Linux Browser on your box

(2) Go here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads  and do bruteforce of ChromeDriver versions

(3) I am using Chrome linux 77 (as of now 9/20/2019) and chromedriver 76.0.3809.25 , worked for me

(4) "Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code" - got nothing with firewall

### (5) Check your Chmod 777 permission for chromeDriver

It's a BROWSER AND CHROME DRIVER MISMTACH , ALL YOU NEED TO DO IS TO CHECK THE COMPATIBILITY